# how to hand calculate RSA decryption exponent (using small numbers)

Tags: modular-arithmetic, cryptography, totient-function

This is a simple exercise to help my personal understanding of RSA. I'm not trying to do anything that will have real world security.

I want to compute the RSA decryption exponent `d`, where `d` = e−1 mod φ(n).

I would prefer to make the calculation using a method similar to this:

```
int d = (k * (p - 1) * (q - 1) + 1) / e;
```

where `e` is the RSA encryption exponent and `p` and `q` are randomly generated primes. I will use small primes (e.g., 7, 13) and I will also pick `e` to be something small like 5.

Why do I want to do it similar to that method? Although I am using the Java language, I am looking for a simple "hand calculation" method. In particular I do **not** want to use something similar to the following method, which is what I find recommended on all the programming-related forums:

```
BigInteger d = e.modInverse(totient);
```

I am trying to avoid calling any external functions. To me modInverse() is a "black box" and I'm trying to avoid those so that I can increase my understanding (although I'm working at a simple level of understanding).

Once I have picked `e`, `p` and `q` how do I find `k`? Once I have `k`, of course, finding `d` is trivial in my example.

The value of `k` should be an integer (it must result in an integer value of `d`, the decryption exponent).

**Example:**

With p=13,q=7,e=5 then `k` = 2 (and therefore, d = 29).

I need to find integer `k` given any small integer `e`, and small primes `p` and `q`. (Also, I would prefer not to iterate, if possible.)

Please keep the answers simple because I don't have any math background. Thanks.

EDIT: claried based on comments.

Comment: Be aware that this is not a programming site, and most people here will not necessarily know Java.

Comment: My question has little or nothing to do with Java. I mentioned Java for context. I'm actually looking for a simple way to compute k WITHOUT using any special Java libraries (or any other special programming techniques).

Comment: @Moo I'm not sure what you are saying. I need simple answers. If you are saying that only certain values of k produce an integer result, that's exactly why I am asking my question. In essence, I'm asking how to compute a k that gives an integer result. (I'm only interested in working with small integers.) Or did I misunderstand you completely?

Comment: @Moo Calcluating  (k * (p - 1) * (q - 1) + 1) / e for k=1...72 gives 15 integers. However, any of these integer values seem to work correctly as the decryption exponent. (So far I have only tested a few and I'll test more.) Could you please make your point more directly? Thanks

Comment: @ Moo: 15 of those give result = 1. They are the same 15 values where  (k * (p - 1) * (q - 1) + 1) / e results in an integer. That's not surprising, but I was hoping for a way to find an integer k without iterating. Are you suggestion there isn't such a way?

Comment: @ Moo - In that data, there is only a single value of 1. Is that your point? What does it mean?

Comment: @ Moo - Maybe my question wasn't clear. I knew I can find a suitable value for k if I simply iterate. I'm trying to find k without iterating, and with a method that can be hand calculated. Is that possible? If so, how? Thanks

Comment: @ Moo - OK. So how do I find an integer k that gives me a valid d without iterating? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For such small values, of course iteration is the simplest method. But for larger parameters, the standard procedure (probably used by Java's `modInverse` method) is the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm#Computing_multiplicative_inverses_in_modular_structures) for computing modular inverses. This is not especially complicated, but neither is it trivial to program. Have fun!

Comment: If I understand it correctly, the extended Euclidean algorithm is an iterative function. Is that correct? If so, I assume that means there is no non-iterative approach that will work. Thanks.